# Finding the residue of $\frac{1}{ \sqrt{z^2+z+1}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I've found the singularity points - $z_1=-1/2+ \sqrt{3} i/2$ and $z_2=-1/2- \sqrt{3} i/2$ . Then i need to determine whether it's a removable singularity, a pole, or an essential singularity. Noting that $|\frac{1}{ \sqrt{z^2+z+1}}|$ approaches infinity as z approaches the points of singularity, i determine that $z_1$ and $z_2$ are poles. Then i need to determine the order of the poles. And this is where i have problems. I consider the function $\frac{1}{f(z)}=\sqrt{z^2+z+1}$ and want to find the order of its zeroes, that will be equal to the order of the poles. But it's first derivative $(\frac{1}{f(z)})'=$ $\frac{2z+1}{2\sqrt{(z^2+z+1)}}$ approaches infinity instead of a constant, as z approaches the zeroes. What does that mean?

Comment: This tells you that the function is not meromorphic. Residues are usually only defined for meromorphic functions, so you could say that this function therefore has no residues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the points where the function $f(z)$ approach infinity are not poles. In other words there exist no integer $n$ such that the function $(z-z_0)^n f(z_0)$ is holomorphic in the vicinity of $z_0$.

Comment: Is it because i need to choose a branch of square root? Because in the textbook, there is an answer, and i havent specified the square root in any way. I know that $\sqrt{z}$ is not analytic along thyoure sae negative real axis, but im not sure what can be said about $\sqrt{z^2+z+1}$ .

Comment: The function $\sqrt{z^2+z+1}$ is not analytic in the neighborhood of both zeros of the expression. They are the branch points (essential singularities) of the function.